# Python typing for class that having methods from decorator

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

The [`dataclasses-json`](https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/#usage) allows code such as:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str

lidatong = Person('lidatong')

# Encoding to JSON
lidatong.to_json()  # '{"name": "lidatong"}'

# Decoding from JSON
Person.from_json('{"name": "lidatong"}')  # Person(name='lidatong')
```

How could I use `typing` to annotate

1. a function which takes an instance whose class has `@dataclass_json` applied, such that the existence of the `to_json` instance method is known to the type checker, and:
2. a function which takes a class having `@dataclass_json` applied, such that the `from_json` class method is known to the type checker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a good use for `typing.Protocol` and `typing.Self` (new in Python 3.11):

```
from typing import Protocol

class JsonAble(Protocol):
    def to_json(self) -> str: ...

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_text: str) -> Self: ...
```

You can then type a function as taking an argument of type `JsonAble` to indicate that it's an object that implements those methods.

If you're not on Python 3.11, there are workarounds involving `typing.TypeVar`; see [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) for details.